# How does this definition capture the intuitive notion of an algebra?

Tags: category-theory, definition, intuition, universal-algebra

On page 15 of [this](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CE0QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.andrew.cmu.edu%2F~awodey%2Fstudents%2Fhughes.pdf&ei=YCKrUrWFEdGviQfxpYCYAg&usg=AFQjCNF3sJ-7wgjy3UPgu0q2AFAbcil_iA&sig2=r258rHDfnrEnZe8dLoeZgw) document, the author writes:

> Definition 1.1.1. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be any category. Given an endofunctor $\Gamma : \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$, a $\Gamma$-algebra consists of a pair $\langle A, \alpha \rangle$ , where $A$ is an object of $E$ and $\alpha : \Gamma A \rightarrow A$ an arrow in $\cal E$. We call $A$ the carrier and $\alpha$ the structure map of the algebra.

I don't get it; how does this definition capture the intuitive notion of an algebra? For a more concrete question, how would an abelian group or a ring be represented under this an approach?

Comment: See example 1.1.4 of that paper to get how you would represent a group. (You need to add in lots of constraints, e.g., one corresponding to associativity, on $\Gamma$, to get a group.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $T$ is a [monad](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad) on a category $\mathcal{E}$, then one can define [$T$-algebras](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+over+a+monad) (I prefer the terminology $T$-modules) and this generalizes all the usual notions of algebraic structures. They are objects $A$ equipped with a morphism $T(A) \to A$ such that the two obvious compatibility conditions are satisfied. For example, if $\mathcal{E}=\mathsf{Set}$ and $G$ is a monoid, then it induces a monad $G \times -$. An algebra for this monad is a set $A$ equipped with a map $G \times A \to A$ written $(g,a) \mapsto ga$ such that $1a=a$ and $g(ha)=(gh)a$. So this is the same as a [$G$-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-set). In general, $T$ contains the "operators" which should "act" on the underlying object of your $T$-algebra. The "action" is precisely the morphism $T(A) \to A$.

Now if $T$ is a plain endofunctor of $\mathcal{E}$, without any monad structure, you can still define [$T$-algebras](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebra+for+an+endofunctor) as above but without any compatibility condition. The category of $T$-algebras is just the comma category $T \downarrow \mathrm{id}_\mathcal{E}$. Still $T$ contains the operators which act on the underlying object of a $T$-algebra, but in this setting these operators don't have to satisfy any compatibility condition (in fact we haven't got a chance to formulate any such conditions).

A very basic but nice example is the functor $1 + \mathrm{id} : \mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$ which sends a set $X$ to $1 + X$, i.e. $X$ with one additional element adjoined. An algebra for this endofunctor is a set $X$ together with a map $1+X \to X$, i.e. an element $x_0 \in X$ and a map $S : X \to X$. This is nothing else than a Peano structure. The recursion theorem tells us precisely that $(\mathbb{N},0,\mathrm{successor})$ is an [initial algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+algebra+of+an+endofunctor). In fact, this is how one defines abstract [natural number objects](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object). Initial algebras turn out to be very interesting, even for very simple functors. For example you can [construct](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23143) the Banach space $L^1[0,1]$ as the initial algebra for the endofunctor $X \mapsto X \times X$ on the category of pointed Banach spaces.

Finally an exercise which may help to understand this concept: Describe the category of algebras for the endofunctor $\mathrm{Sym}^2 : \mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$ which maps $X$ to $\mathrm{Sym}^2(X) = X^2 / ((x,y) = (y,x))_{x,y \in X}$.

Comment: It's not quite the comma category $(T \downarrow \mathcal{E})$, but it is a full subcategory thereof.

Comment: Ah, ok, it's the "path" category $T \to \mathrm{id}$.